# enable mod_rewrite

Tags: magento-1.7, overrides

I know this topic has been posted before, but my problem seems to be slightly different and also I am only a beginner and the previous answers were too complicated for me.

Here is my problem:
I have been trying to move my website from Local to Live. I have successfully moved the files and the database. I can now access my home page, but my admin page can only be accessed by www.mydomain.com/index.php/admin, I want to access it through www.mydomain.com/admin. I have read that this is due to my mod_rewrite not working.

**Can someone please tell me how to enable my mod_rewrite in simple terms?**

My local server is MAMP.
I am using cPanel.
I have been using [this](http://www.dmarkweb.com/how-to-move-magento-from-local-to-live-server.html) step-by-step guide to move my website from Local to Live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the ability to use `mod_rewrite` to clean up the urls **isn't available** for admin, so all answers would be custom htaccess rules, which you have referenced you're not comfortable with.

@clockworkgeek has an extension that will do this, but I haven't tried it:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/clockworkgeek/extension/3692/clockworkgeek_adminrewrites

If you would like to proceed, there are some suggestions at the below link. The following quote is also a walkthrough of how it would be accomplished via htaccess:

> I created a directory named “admin” in my document root. I then used a
>   .htaccess file which restricted access to this directory.
>
> In the site’s main .htaccess file, directly after the following line:
>
> ```
> RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
> I added these lines: 
> # These lines rewrite /index.php/admin to /admin.
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/admin.*$
> RewriteRule ^index.php/admin(.*) /admin$1 [R]
>
> # These lines are needed to prevent Apache from serving
> # up the /admin folders directory index when a request is
> # made for "/admin" or "/admin/".
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/?$
> RewriteRule (.*) $1/dashboard
> ```
>
> Now, If I go to a URL like this, 
>   http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/admin/index/index/key/mykey/

**Source**: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/34357/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have had a look at the extension and I will think about installing it, if I do install it I will report back with how well it works.

Before I started using MAMP and creating sites locally, I just created them on the live server, and my admin would always be located at www.mydomain.com/admin. But when I moved my site from local to live it changed to www.mydomain.com/index.php/admin. You have informed that mod_rewrite is not available to clean up URL's for admin, but do you know why my admin has moved to /index.php/admin in the first place?

Thanks again